# Looking to use a sub domain for the customer area of a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I am new to this site and I am a designer more so than a programmer. I have thoroughly searched for a fix or answer to this but so far found nothing.

I have a website (www.face.eu.com) that is powered by WordPress. We have customers that can log in to the site in order to download tools.

What I want to achieve is a secure area that the login customers are directed to. So, my idea was to have another installation of WordPress on a sub domain (www.users.face.eu.com) and after logging in they are directed here, the site uses the same theme therefore looks the same.

Is this possible and would it keep the user logged in after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different installation of Wordpress, then no. These two installes have different cookie secrets in `wp-config.php` and so cannot share a login.

However, you should be able to accomplish this using the Network feature in Wordpress 3, which was previously named WPMU (Wordpress MultiUser). On http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network is a detailed tutorial on how to get this functioning.

If you have completed these steps, you can spawn a different blog on a subdomain, yet share plugins, themes and users.